# SpringData Mongo @Column equivalent annotation (@Property?)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a SpringData Mongo equivalent of the JPA @Column annotation?

Basically, I've got a POJO with a property that I want to store in Mongo with a different name. So, the following object:

```
public class Pojo{
    @Property("bar")
    private String foo = "Hello World";
}
```

would be persisted as:

```
{
    "_class":"com.example.Pojo",
    "bar" : "Hello World"
}
```

*Note:* I don't want to use the `MappingMongoConverter` to explicitly do it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Spring Data [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations) lists `@Field` as the annotation to customize the key and ordering of properties mapped to a MongoDB document.

Comment: Well, I feel a little dumb considering I've looked on multiple occasions. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to reach here finally. Was looking for this for a really long time today.

Comment: Updated link : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations

Answer (score 9):

You can use `@Field`

It lets you define custom key name in DB and the insert order